# Format Excel to Display Second Time Zone in Graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts, axis

I need to make my Y axis in a graph show the time in HH:MM (local) format as well as HH:MM +/- offset for another timezone.

Form example:

09:00 EST 06:00 PST

Is there some sort of custom format code I could use?  Can I do somehow take the standard format code:

[$-400]hh:mm:ss AM/PM;@

And do something like the following to adjust for the time difference?

[$-400]hh(-3):mm:ss AM/PM;@

Comment: I don't know if it's possible the way you describe it, but I would put two column with the date and format I'm lookink for and then concatenate them in a third colum used for the axis.